# Compile all SASS files in folder to single CSS file

Tags: css, sass, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I have a subfolder which contains sass files. I want to compile these files into a single css file called `client-styles.css`, which will be stored in the same folder.

I have a `gulpfile` set up which looks through the `modules` folder, finds subfolders and the sass files in them and compiles those sass files into css (storing them in the same folder).

The folder I was to compile is called `client-styles`. Here is my folder structure:

```
theme
   - assets
      - src
         - sass
           - client-styles
              - _buttons.scss
              - _typography.scss
              - _core.scss
           - config
              - _mixins.scss
              - _grid.scss
              - _variables.scss
         - styles.scss
   - modules
      - hero
         - hero.html
         - hero.scss
         - hero.css (this file is created when running gulp)
   gulpfile.js
```

`Gulp` compiles my modules css file correctly, but with my current setup, nothing compiles for my `client-styles.css`

Here is my current `gulpfile.js`

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var postcss = require('gulp-postcss');

var paths = {
    styles: {
        src: 'modules/**/*.scss',
        dest: 'modules'
    }
}

function scss() {
    return gulp.src(paths.styles.src)
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: 'compressed' }))
        .pipe(postcss([autoprefixer()]))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.dest));
}

exports.scss = scss

var themeStyles = {
    styles: {
        src: 'assets/src/sass/client-styles/*.scss',
        dest: 'sass'
    }
}

function themescss() {
    return gulp.src(themeStyles.styles.src)
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: 'compressed' }))
        .pipe(postcss([autoprefixer()]))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(themeStyles.styles.dest));
}



function watch() {
    scss();
    themescss();
    gulp.watch(paths.styles.src, scss);
    gulp.watch(themeStyles.styles.src, scss);
}

exports.watch = watch;
```

Am I far off?

**Edit:**

`styles.scss`

```
@import "config/grid.scss";  
@import "config/mixins.scss";  
@import "config/variables.scss";
```

**Edit 2**

Have updated my folder structure slightly to the following

```
theme
   assets
      src 
        sass
           config
              _variables.scss
              _mixins.scss
              _grid.scss
           client-styles
              _core.scss
              _buttons.scss
              _typography.scss
         _config.scss
         styles.scss
```

**_config.scss**

```
@import "config/grid.scss";  
@import "config/mixins.scss";  
@import "config/variables.scss";
```

The reason I have this file is so that I can use `@import "../../assets/src/sass/config.scss";` to use the `vars` and `mixins` in another file (like `hero.scss`).

**styles.scss**

```
@import "client-styles/buttons";
@import "client-styles/typography";
@import "client-styles/core";
```

Latest `gulpfile.js`

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var postcss = require('gulp-postcss');

// for module scss build

var paths = {
    styles: {
        src: 'modules/**/*.scss',
        dest: 'modules'
    }
}

function scss() {
    return gulp.src(paths.styles.src)
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: 'compressed' }))
        .pipe(postcss([autoprefixer()]))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.dest));
}

exports.scss = scss;

// for theme sass build

var themeStyles = {
    stylestheme: {
        src: 'assets/src/client-styles/*.scss',
        dest: 'sass'
    }
}

function themescss() {
    return gulp.src(themeStyles.stylestheme.src)
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: 'compressed' }))
        .pipe(postcss([autoprefixer()]))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(themeStyles.stylestheme.dest));
}

exports.themescss = themescss;


// watch

function watch() {
    scss();
    themescss();
    gulp.watch(paths.styles.src, scss);
    gulp.watch(themeStyles.stylestheme.src, scss);
}

exports.watch = watch;
```

**Test:**

Have commented out first watch task to see if it changes things. Doens't work. Still no css file created with client-styles folder scss.

Gulpfile.js for reference:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var postcss = require('gulp-postcss');


var themeStyles = {
    stylestheme: {
        src: 'assets/src/client-styles/*.scss',
        dest: 'assets/src/sass'
    }
}

function themescss() {
    return gulp.src(themeStyles.stylestheme.src)
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: 'compressed' }))
        .pipe(postcss([autoprefixer()]))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(themeStyles.stylestheme.dest));
}

exports.themescss = themescss;

// watch

function watch() {
    themescss();
    gulp.watch(themeStyles.stylestheme.src, themeStyles);
}

exports.watch = watch;
```

Comment: When you name a .scss file, the underscore prefix means that it's a partial that you have to import in another file. You could have a style.scss file in which you'll import all your partials.

Comment: @AmauryHanser Hi, sorry, I do have a `styles.scss`, I've edited my question to show the folder structure and how the file looks.

Comment: In your variable *themeStyles* you specify the path `assets/src/client-styles/*.scss` but your *styles.scss* is in `assets/src/*.scss`. Is it a typo ?

Comment: @AmauryHanser  - Good spot, yes the correct directory for `themeStyles` is ` src: 'assets/src/sass/client-styles/*.scss',`. I've updated my question with the correct path

Answer (score 2):

Easy fix for your config, is to add new file `client-styles.scss` near your `styles.scss` with content:

```
@import "client-styles/buttons";
@import "client-styles/typography";
@import "client-styles/core";
```

and amend path in *themeStyles* function:

```
var themeStyles = {
  styles: {
    src: 'assets/src/**/*.scss',
    dest: 'assets/src/sass'
  }
}
```

This changes will give you 2 css files, one `styles.css` and second is `client-styles.scss`.

Also, i strongly recommend you to look into [7 in 1 pattern](https://github.com/HugoGiraudel/sass-boilerplate) - it saved a lot of time for me when i started writing styles with Scss ;)

Good luck!

*P.S. by default Gulp will only extract files that don't have underscore in name: `style.scss` - yes, `_style.scss` - no. So it's better to have only 1 file in wich we want include all project styles.*

Comment: Hey, thanks, the 7 in 1 looks handy, will definitely explore that. As for the question, I've made the changes you suggested, no new file seems to be created for me? I've updated my question with my current code and structure just so we're updated. If you could take a look, in case I've missed / misunderstood something from your answer

Comment: @freddy hi) if i understand correctly, Gulp would create file, but not in correct folder. Can you search project for css-files? 

Also I edited my answer and changed themedStyles.styles.dest to `assets/src/sass` - i think it should put css file in desired folder.

Comment: Hi, I've searched the theme, and no new css file was created. I then changed my `dest` to `dest: 'assets/src/sass'` (as you mentioned) and still no css file is being generated anywhere in my theme?

Comment: If no file created, i suppose Gulp doesn't work at all ;( 

Can you add `const watch = gulp.parallel(watch);` at the end of file, before the `exports.watch` 

Also, this config https://gist.github.com/jeromecoupe/0b807b0c1050647eb340360902c3203a is written in Gulp(v4)  - maybe we both missing some key detail. 

As a last resort, you can copy example config, and change only `pathVariables`, and from that point - start removing plugins that you don't need.

Don't forget to do `npm i`, and `gulp watch` after config changes

Comment: That's what's confusing me though. Gulp is working, because it is compiling `scss()`. Whenever I create a new `.scss` file under `modules/folder_name`, a new `css` file is created. Just doesn't seem to work for when trying to compile it for the `client-styles` folder

Comment: maybe just first `watch` function works, and the second one ignored by gulp? Could you try to comment `gulp.watch(paths.styles.src, scss);` ?

Comment: I've tried that, I've updated my question to show the test I ran, took out the `scss()` function, still no css file for client-styles after running `gulp watch`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210592/discussion-between-ve1ikiy-and-freddy).